# Why does python allow you to create dictionaries with duplicate keys

Tags: python

Dictionaries in python are supposed to have unique keys. Why are you allowed to do this...

```
d = {'a' : 'b', 'a' : 'c'}
```

Shouldn't this throw some sort of error?

Comment: You  may be interested in reading [the Python bug report about this exact issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue16385). Resolution: rejected.

Comment: why should it ? the keys are unique still, the value is just over written as is expected. There are no duplicate keys. I am sure this is a duplicate question as well I just can not find the duplicate right now.

Comment: Good question - I never knew that.   Interesting rationale: Terry seems to think that there are use cases that warrant having this behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> d = {'a' : 'b', 'a' : 'c'}
>>> d
{'a': 'c'}
```

No, it's just you're initializing a dict using pre-existing key, which just over-writes the current value for the existing key.

```
>>> dis.dis("d = {'a' : 'b', 'a' : 'c'}")
  1           0 BUILD_MAP                2
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 ('b')
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('a')
              9 STORE_MAP
             10 LOAD_CONST               2 ('c')
             13 LOAD_CONST               1 ('a')
             16 STORE_MAP
             17 STORE_NAME               0 (d)
             20 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             23 RETURN_VALUE

>>> dis.dis("d={};d['a']='b';d['a']='c'")
  1           0 BUILD_MAP                0
              3 STORE_NAME               0 (d)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 ('b')
              9 LOAD_NAME                0 (d)
             12 LOAD_CONST               1 ('a')
             15 STORE_SUBSCR
             16 LOAD_CONST               2 ('c')
             19 LOAD_NAME                0 (d)
             22 LOAD_CONST               1 ('a')
             25 STORE_SUBSCR
             26 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             29 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see, two ways of initializing are somewhat alike: first key-value is stored first then second.

Comment: Which is exactly what they are asking. They are wondering **why it is not an error**.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't. It just overwrites the keys.

```
>>> d = {'a' : 'b', 'a' : 'c'}
>>> d
{'a': 'c'}
```

Is it an error to overwrite a key? It shouldn't. Otherwise, you'd have a million errors when you try and update things in a dictionary. The reason for why I think there's no error is this (explaining code in english):

```
d is a dictionary.
there is a key and a value. ('a' and 'b')
Pair them up and enter them, while saving them.
New entry ('a' and 'c')
key 'a' already exists; update value.
```